# Create table by Athena using the last folder in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm using the following code for creating table from my bucket data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acc_log_file_o`.`Acc_log_2022031502` (

  `ad_id` string,
 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://yyy.pixs/2022/03/15/02/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false','compressionType'='gzip');
```

My bucket is updated every minute, and every hour created another folder.
I want to query the last and the second last folder.
for example, if the date-time right now is `03.15.22 06:34`
I need to use this URL `s3://yyy.pixs/2022/03/15/06/` and `s3://yyy.pixs/2022/03/15/05/`
(seperate query for the last and the second last is good enough)

I found the following explanation but I don't understand if I can use it and how to do so.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/databrew/latest/dg/datasets.multiple-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena will automatically search all files in the given `LOCATION`, including files in all subfolders. It is not possible to specify in which subfolders to search for files.

However, you might consider [Partitioning Data in Athena - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html). This is where the name of the folder conveys some specific information (eg month or day) and Athena can intelligently only look in folders that match a `WHERE` clause. This way, it can skip-over folders that do not contain relevant information.

When data is added to a partitioned table via Amazon Athena, the folder naming will be handled automatically by Athena. However, if the data is stored outside of Athena, then Athena needs to be 'told' about the partitions. Therefore, it is a little bit more complex than simply storing data in a new folder.

You might be able to use DataBrew to convert your data into a suitable format, but the page you linked is not directly relevant to Amazon Athena.